# Azure MSI: Login failed for user ''

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect from an App Service to a database, using an MSI token, and am getting

```
Login failed for user ''.
```

WHen I deployed the App Service using ARM I produced an Output that ensured that it created a Service Principal:

```
 {
  "principalId":"98f2c1f2-0a86-4ff1-92db-d43ec0edxxxx","
  tenantId":"e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx",
  "type":"SystemAssigned"
 }
```

I've also checked in Kudu the environment variables and have:

```
MSI_ENDPOINT = http://127.0.0.1:41239/MSI/token/
MSI_SECRET = 7C1B16Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have provided in the Azure Portal a connection string as follows:

```
Data Source=nzmoebase0001bt.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=nzmoebase0001bt;Connect Timeout=300;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

> As an offside, ain't that cool that MSI (theoretically) allows one to cut/paste from source code to a public forum without fear of leaving a secret?! Just sayin'.... Now...if only I could get it to work!!!

I've added the principal to the database as an Owner...

But I'm still getting:

```
Login failed for user ''.
```

What else should I try?

Thank you.

@juunas: the token is being added using:

```
    static async Task AttachAccessTokenToDbConnection(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = dbConnection as SqlConnection;
        if (sqlConnection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string msiEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_ENDPOINT");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msiEndpoint))
        {
            return;
        }

        var msiSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_SECRET");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msiSecret))
        {
            return;
        }

        // To get around:
        // "Cannot set the AccessToken property if 'UserID', 'UID', 'Password', or 'PWD' has been specified in connection string."
        var terms = new[] {"UserID","Password","PWD=","UID=" };
        string connectionString = dbConnection.ConnectionString;

        foreach (var term in terms)
        {
            if (connectionString.Contains(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        string accessToken = await AppCoreDbContextMSITokenFactory.GetAzureSqlResourceTokenAsync();
        sqlConnection.AccessToken = accessToken;
    }
```

Update:
Some progress (not entirely sure what's changed), getting from Entity Framework

```
This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.
```

I Added `Persist Security Info = True` as per several recommendations on the net, but didn't change much.

```
Data Source=nzmoebase0001bt.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=nzmoebase0001bt;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Persist Security Info = True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

As per @evilSnobu, I did finally get tracing on and captured the token:

```
 .eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI....
```

WHich decoded using jwt.io gave:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "FSimuFrFNoC0sJXGmv13nNZceDc",
  "kid": "FSimuFrFNoC0sJXGmv13nNZceDc"
}.{
  "aud": "https://database.windows.net/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx/",
  "iat": 1522783025,
  "nbf": 1522783025,
  "exp": 1522786925,
  "aio": "Y2NgYPjNdyJd9zrzpLavJSEzNIuPAAA=",
  "appid": "d1057cea-461b-4946-89a9-d76439c2xxxx",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx/",
  "oid": "98f2c1f2-0a86-4ff1-92db-d43ec0edxxxx",
  "sub": "98f2c1f2-0a86-4ff1-92db-d43ec0edxxxx",
  "tid": "e6d2d4cc-b762-486e-8894-4f5f440dxxxx",
  "uti": "59bqKWiSL0Gf0bTCI0AAAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

Which to my untrained eye looks great (?). But I still get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
```

Which appears to be from a deeper message tie to EntityFramework's startup scheam checking process:

```
[InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]
```

Any and all advice greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the code where you get the access token and attach it to the db connection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token

Comment: First make sure you get a valid token (print it out), look at it in https://jwt.ms. I believe you still need to follow these few steps even for App Service, although not terribly sure on that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql#grant-your-vm-access-to-a-database-in-an-azure-sql-server

Comment: I've updated the question to add the info you requested. Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm chasing the "This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database" error now, following this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

I think it's key to include the following line after you assign your token:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDatabaseContext>(null);
```

In my case we had some code explicitly running Entity Framework Migrations that resulted in the error. When we disabled it, the app started working as expected.

Comment: I'm confused, does adding that mean that migrations will no longer run? I've also tried to follow that document, and I'd fully expect this error to be returned when running in production, because I haven't specified a user, yet when I do specify a user, I get `Cannot set the AccessToken property if 'UserID', 'UID', 'Password', or 'PWD' has been specified in connection string.` locally and `Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Connection refused` in production.